# how to style react library components

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I am using this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-picker
to display a date picker in my application. 
I am used to working with Angular and relatively new to react and have little to no exposure on how to style components provided by these libraries.

The below is the set-up for the date picker in the react render() functions return:

```
<DatePicker
    name="date"
    value={Moment(values.date, 'YYYY/MM/DD').toDate()}
    onChange={this.handleDateChange}
    maxDate={maxDate}
    minDate={minDate}
/>
```

The picker generated by the datepicker is an input box and I want to remove the top and side borders to make it resemble the material-ui pickers which are just their textfield with type='date' (https://material-ui.com/demos/pickers/) .

On a different note. The material text-field has a label property but the api for the date-picker api doens't mention anything about a label prop but is there a way to add it or is the best approach to just insert a div above the tag and style it to look like a label?

Thank You~

Update:

[image]

playing around with the console I found that the className attribute applys it's styles to the react-date-picker class whereas the border is affected by the react-date-picker___wrapper class. How can I change the styles of this class using the className property provided by the api currently playing around with no success T_T

Comment: you can add any styles you want by adding the style prop. Also i dont think you need that library the material UI that you are going for uses the browsers default date picker and only styles a simple input tag. Add styles like this:
<input type='date' style={{ border: 'none' , color: 'red'}}
note the values have to be strings

Comment: Yeah, it seems simpler but there this library is built on the react-calendar which suits my needs better.

Comment: The library you supplied does nothing special other than creating a custom styled date picker. Either way just set a  style={{}} on the <DatePicker /> and play around with it.

Comment: well that was the first thing I tried but it throws this error: Type '{ style: {}; name: string; value: Date; onChange: (e: any) => void; maxDate: Date; minDate: Date; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DatePickerProps'.   Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DatePickerProps'

Comment: I think instead of using inline styling the api provides a className prop which you can feed to affect the div of the date-picker or the calendar so I'll try using that.

Comment: didn't work the className attribute affects on the values inside the textbox -_-

Comment: Yes the className will apply to the parent element. In your custom class you can then target child elements. Also the default example at http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-date-picker/ doesnt even have borders, and most inputs use outline not border anyway. I would either ditch this component and style a nice input the way you want it and use the default date picker Or you are gonna have to spend some time understanding CSS and specifically css selector specificity so you can modify this component the way you want it.

Comment: I do not want to use the material Input. I guess I'll try to figure out if it's possible to remove the borders through css otherwise I guess I'll find another library